# Is there a way to test private functions in modules in ExUnit of Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Functions defined by `defp` aren't exported so I can't execute them in places other than in the module.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to write a macro that expands to `defp` in DEV and PROD Mix environments, and `def` in a TEST environment?

Comment: @TalkLittle Yes, it's possible. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

No, there is no way to test them via ExUnit.

I personally avoid testing private functions because usually you end up testing implementation instead of behaviour and those tests fail as soon as you need to change the code. Instead, I test the expected behaviour via the public functions, breaking them in small, consistent chunks.

Comment: FYI, this is good advice regardless of language or testing library.

Comment: I tend to disagree respectfully: There are two ways to test. On a beha

Comment: sorry got interrupted editing this. Globally agree, but feel that some private functions can benefit from tests for the purpose of refactoring.

Comment: @lab419 maybe, but that's usually a clue that your private function should grow and become its own object (in OOP) or public function in a utility module (in FP)

Comment: @tompave I guess you are right in some cases, however then I would like to give restricted access to that utility module for my library users but that seems a little bit complicated. Still I feel that the refactoring use case is underestimated.

Comment: I often face a scenario where I have to test infrastructure that is only available in real integration tests when targeting only public functions. The functionality which abstracts away the environment should be private, however they could (and must be) unit-tested, but cannot :/

Comment: that moment when you realise the accepted answer is Jose's, and you really don't need to read the other answers.

Comment: @lab419 You can add `@moduledoc false` to a module to exclude it and its functions from documentation. The functions would still be callable tho. I'm kind of vacillating between your preference and the idea of just making the functions public. In a sense they're not-interesting, and it seems reasonable to want to test functions but not expose them as part of the application's or libary's public API. Maybe, in practice, it's sufficient to document that a module or function is not part of the 'public API', i.e. is subject to removal or other 'breaking changes'.

Comment: @whossname Don't you subscribe to [Death of the Author](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor), at least somewhat? José may have created Elixir, and even actively maintains it, but all of its user's dreams for it are 'real' and 'valid' too! And maybe he can be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: Death of the author isn't really relevant here. This is more an opinion of someone I respect.I don't agree with his position on mocks, but I followed his advice here and it turned out to be completely correct.

Answer (score 26):

In your module definition, you can a `@compile` directive to export your private functions *only* in the test environment.

```
defmodule Foo do
  @compile if Mix.env == :test, do: :export_all

  # This will be exported for tests
  defp bar() do
  ... code ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Update: This will issue a warning in Elixir 1.5 so it might not be the best way.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to change the visibility of a function depending on the environment using a macro:

```elixir
defmacro defp_testable(head, body \\ nil) do
  if Mix.env == :test do
    quote do
      def unquote(head) do
        unquote(body[:do])
      end
    end
  else
    quote do
      defp unquote(head) do
        unquote(body[:do])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can expose functions to your tests as follows:

```elixir
defp_testable myfunc do
  ...
end
```

I recommend using this sparingly for the reasons given in José's answer. It's not a substitute for testing the external behavior of a module. It can be valuable in certain scenarios, though.

([Source](https://github.com/wistia/ex_ex/blob/master/lib/ex_ex/ex_unit.ex))

Comment: @TalkLittle Indeed it does. The macro only affects visibility and leaves the params/body unchanged.

Comment: this is not a very good idea, because this will not  detect potential bugs when private functions are called by error.

Comment: @lab419 That's a fair criticism. This technique is not a substitute for other testing methods that would detect improper use of private functions, and it should be used with care. As you and others have noted, though, this can be useful for refactoring and integration test scenarios.

Comment: @acj sorry if I was not clear, if you change the privacy of a function depending on the mix environment, all you test is the test mix environment. You are not testing the dev or prod environement anymore because it does not contain the same code. And what is worse, you will have false negatives because you will have public functions in your test env which are private elsewhere. HTH

Comment: @lab419 I understand, and I agree with you. :)  Anyone who chooses to use this should be careful and should have an additional mechanism for testing dev/prod environments.

Answer (score 3):

Private functions cannot be called from outside their modules, even in the context of testing with ExUnit.

Others suggested complex ways to expose private functions for testing, hence I suggest these other two which seem much simpler:

1) make the function you want to test public, but mark it with `@doc false`, thus meaning that it is not part of the public API of your module.

2) alternatively, if the function you want to test is `defp foo` then create a `def test_foo`, in the same module, which takes the arguments you want to vary during your tests, adapts them to what `foo` expects, and finally calls `foo`. You can also generate your special test function only during testing like this

```
  if Mix.env == :test do
    def test_foo ...
  end
```

Any of these alternatives is simpler and requires no extra dependencies in your project.

Of course, as others mentioned, the general rule is to avoid testing private functions, but sometimes testing them is the way to ease testing and raise the coverage of your tests.

Good coding!